# How to save the generated 3d representation of the structure(s) by Viewer3d in Py4vasp?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, python, visualization-software

I used py4vasp to calculate structure from data and then I displayed them in a structure viewer (Viewer3d) by this line: `calc.structure[:].plot()`. It returns a visualization of the structures as a 3d figure.

How I can save this 3d figure?

Also, If I read the structural information into a dictionary by this: `calc.structure[:].read()`, how I can plot the structures?

Here is the code which I used in the Jupyter notebook:

```
from py4vasp import Calculation
calc = Calculation.from_path(".")
calc.structure[:].plot()
```

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago. Is [this account also yours?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users/6587/abolfazl-tavakoli) Can we merge them so that your profile here is connected to the rest of your SE network profile? If you tried to remove the second part of the question, was that because you've solved that part and are still in need of an answer to the first part?

Comment: @Aaryan Could you please add a link to a folder with all the necessary input files such as **INCAR, POTCAR, POSCAR, KPQINTS**  and output file : **vaspout.h5** ? These files are required to run the line : `calc = Calculation.from_path(".")`

Answer (score 2):

Since we do not have all the files specific to your calculation such as the INCAR, POTCAR, POSCAR, KPQINTS and vaspout.h5, I will demonstrate how to save a viewer3d structure to a PNG image using a sample viewer3d structure.

From [py4vasp source code](https://github.com/vasp-dev/py4vasp/blob/33cee0184f1af1b9fce69d8bb2c773f506b13f25/src/py4vasp/_data/viewer3d.py), we can see that the viewer is a: `NGLWidget`

All the following code are written on a Google Colab notebook:

```
from google.colab import output
output.enable_custom_widget_manager()

import nglview as nv
import ipywidgets as w
import time
import threading
from pathlib import Path
view = nv.demo()
view

type(view)
>> nglview.widget.NGLWidget # This matches with what we get from py4vasp
```

The viewer3d structure looks like this:

[image]

The following code saves the viewer3d as a PNG image.

```
output_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/output/img.png"

def save_image(view):
    img = view.render_image()
    
    while not img.value:
        time.sleep(0.1)
    
    with open(output_path, "wb") as f:
        f.write(img.value)

Path(output_path).unlink(missing_ok=True)

thread = threading.Thread(target=save_image, args=(view, ), daemon=False)

thread.start()
```

The PNG image is now saved at the output path.